# Upload codeigniter htaccess just not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, upload

I created exact same copy as [CI User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html), I even changed 
`$this->upload->do_upload("name_of_file_input");` 
I tried both

```
./data/
./application/data/
```

as my folder to upload, CHMOD 0777, and still upload does not work.
I started FF and FireBug to see what headers I am sending/getting from my localhost and I figured that problem could be in .htaccess file but no so sure...

I work on subfolder `localhost/something/ (or http://192.168.0.101/sms/)` 
my routes.php should be fine well no 404s or any other problems besides upload script
Also weird thing is I have to make form like this

```
<?=form_open_multipart("/sms/upload/do_upload")?>
```

which creates this

```
<form action="http://localhost/sms/sms/upload/do_upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

note **double sms/sms/** which is obviously wrong, but my htaccess it redirects correctly as you can see here

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2012 01:49:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
Location: http://192.168.0.101/sms/upload
Content-Length: 337
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

if I create form like this

```
<?=form_open_multipart("/upload/do_upload")?>
```

it throws me a error well of course it does

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2012 01:52:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
Location: http://192.168.0.101/upload/do_upload
```

and obviously **http://192.168.0.101/upload** does not exist on my localhost my whole installation is under subfolder **/sms/**
my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# mod_rewrite rules
RewriteEngine on

# The RewriteBase of the system (if you are using this sytem in a sub-folder).
 RewriteBase /sms/

# This will make the site only accessible without the "www."
# (which will keep the subdomain-sensive config file happy)
# If you want the site to be accessed WITH the "www."
# comment-out the following two lines.
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192.168.0.101$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.0.101/$1 [L,R=301]

# If a controler can't be found - then issue a 404 error from PHP
# Error messages (via the "error" plugin)
# ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/403/
# ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/404/
# ErrorDocument 500 /index.php/500/

# Deny any people (or bots) from the following sites: (to stop spam comments)
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} nienschanz\.ru [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} porn\.com
# RewriteRule .* - [F]
# Note: if you are having trouble from a certain URL just
# add it above to forbide all visitors from that site.

# You can also uncomment this if you know the IP:
# Deny from 192.168.1.1

# If the file is NOT the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
# Hide all PHP files so none can be accessed by HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1

# If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

#<ifModule mod_expires.c>
#  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
#       ExpiresActive on
#       ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
#   </filesmatch>
#</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xhtml text/html text/plain text/xml
text/javascript application/x-javascript text/css
</IfModule>
FileTag none
```

### NEW info:

it seems that after hitting "upload" button it is redirected "somewhere" (with data "attached"), and from "somewhere" it is redirected to my actual upload script that does all the work (without data "attached") therefore I think it is problem of .htaccess.
CI throws this error

> You did not select a file to upload.

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './data/';
    //$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    //$config['max_size']   = '100';
    //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
    //$config['max_height']  = '768';
    //$config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("userfile"))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
   }
  }
 ?>
```

it is copy of CI guide I linked above

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `.htaccess`

Comment: Alright, but where is the problem then? :) I even put on profiler to see POST data and it is always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally :)
the problem was in relative / absolute paths or actually my CodeIgniter settings, there is this line in my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sms/';
```

which is all good, but in my .htaccess file there is no localhost mentioned (there is **IP**).

The whole problem is solved by putting same "path" in both config files and .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use relative links? (remove the initial slash '/')

You created the destination folder for the upload files and changed the permission?

Try to remove the RewriteBase /sms/

And if you want that the url be the same, change the documentRoot in apache config file

Hope this can help you. If not, put more from your code.

Comment: Relative links with a mod_rewritten website are very difficult to implement, since a user can feasibly be any number of subdirectories in.

Comment: I make my websites with relative links in my entire life and I don't see any kind of problem, unlike, has become extremely usefully to transport the sites between the servers - more in http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html

Comment: So how would you go about putting relative links in the page `example.com/users/view/username/profile/edit/` when it's the same page as `example.com/users/view/username/comment/add/`?

Comment: I don't understand, why create 2 URLs that point to the same content? and, suppose you are in page example.com/users/view/username/profile/edit/ and want to create a link to example.com/users/view/username/comment/add/ I just put in the href=../../comment/add

Comment: Relative links: codeigniter itself creates absolute links. Folder: is created and put on 0777

Comment: There is no point to remove RewriteBase /sms/ the whole codeigniter setting would be usseles what I mean site won't "work".

Comment: I never use RewriteBase, I use a DNS that interprets the subdomains and making with apache can handle it. But when i don't use Subdomains I just change the DocumentRoot in the httpd.conf, I just telling you to try something like this, cuz I don't see why codeigniter isn't working in your case..